# How do I set param to FromURI using URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

So I have the following Control:

```
public class ItemQuery {
    public int storeID { get; set; }
    public int companyID { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public string itemDescription { get; set; }
    public string itemPLU { get; set; }
    public string itemUPC { get; set; }
    public int supplierID { get; set; }
    public string partNumber { get; set; }
}
public class ItemController : ApiController {
    public List<Item> FindItem([FromUri]ItemQuery query) {
        return new List<Item>();
    }

}
```

I am trying to hit it with this request:

```
http://localhost:43751/api/Item/Find?query[storeID]=1
```

And it's not working with but giving me this error:

```
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
```

What should I do?  Here is my Routing information, I haven't changed anything yet:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should make sure you're using System.Web.Http namespace for Web Api.

Then change the method name to `GetFindItem` or add `HttpGet` Attribute, like below:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<Item> FindItem([FromUri]ItemQuery query){  //   }
```

Also your query string should be like below:

```
http://localhost:43751/api/Item/?storeId=1&companyID=2&itemName=ABC&itemDescription=good&itemPLU=aa&itemUPC=dd&&supplierID=1&partNumber=number
```

If you're using Ajax to call the Web API, below is an example

**Js file**

```
var data = {
    storeID: 1,
    companyID: 1,
    itemName: 'Test',
    itemDescription: 'Description',
    itemPLU: 'Test',
    itemUPC: 'Test',
    supplierID: 1,
    partNumber: 'Description',
};
$.getJSON('/api/Item', { query:data }, function() {
       alert("success");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined routing for WebApi.

The `routes.MapRoute` that you have is for MVC. To define routes for WebApi, you will need to use `routes.MapHttpRoute`